# How Many Ways Can 3 x's 3 y's and 3 z's be arranged so that no consecutive triple of the same letter appears

Tags: solution-verification, inclusion-exclusion

**My Question**

I want to know two things: is my solution correct, and is there another, more clever, way to solve it?

**My Solution**

There are a total of $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$ arrangements of $xxxyyyzzz$. We must subtract the amount of these arrangements with consecutive triples from the total to get our answer.

$A =$ an arrangment where xxx appears

$B =$ an arrangement where yyy appears

$C =$ an arrangement where zzz appears

We must find $|A\cup B\cup C|$ and subtract it from the total number of arrangements

By the inclusion-exclusion principle, $|A\cup B\cup C| = (|A|+|B|+|C|) - (|A\cap B| + |A\cap C| + |B\cap C|) + (|A\cap B\cap C|)$

$|A| = |B| = |C| = \frac{7!}{3!3!1!}$

$|A\cap B| = |A \cap C| = |B\cap C|= \frac{5!}{3!1!1!}$

$|A\cap B\cap C| = 3!$

Therefore, our answer $= \frac{9!}{3!3!3!} -3*\frac{7!}{3!3!1!} + 3*\frac{5!}{3!1!1!} - 3!$

Comment: I think you have missing factors in the 2nd and 3rd terms, but otherwise this looks fine.

Comment: @user84413 I don't think so. I believe our book used that exact formula in the 3 set example.

Comment: You're using the right formula, but I believe you want to take into account that there are 3 sets and 3 double intersections when using the formula.

Comment: Ahhhh, I thought you meant for the original formula. You were talking about the last part yeah? I forgot to put the 3x in my answer. I'll edit that.

Comment: It looks good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to work this (which is slightly more complicated):

Let $A_i$ be the set of arrangements which have the same letter in places $i, i+1, i+2$ for $1\le i\le7$.

Then $\displaystyle|A_i^{c}\cap\cdots\cap A_7^{c}|=\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}-\sum|A_i|+\sum|A_i\cap A_j|-\sum|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|$

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.35 in}=\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}-7\cdot 3\cdot\frac{6!}{3!3!}+10\cdot3\cdot2-3!=1314.$